# Swap div position with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to swap div position when clicked **only with the first div in stack**. So when div 2 or 3 is clicked it will swap with the first child of 
parent in DOM and when the first child of parent in DOM is clicked nothing should happen.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exc5m046/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="move">div 1</div>
    <div id="two" class="move">div 2</div>
    <div id="three" class="move">div 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    color:#fff;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
#container div {
    position: relative;
    margin:10px;
    background:#ff00ab;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

jQuery

```jquery
var animating = false;

$('#container').on('click', '.move', function () {

    var clickedDiv = $(this).closest('div'),

    prevDiv = clickedDiv.prev(),
    distance = clickedDiv.offset().left - prevDiv.offset().left;

    if (prevDiv.length) {
        animating = true;
        $.when(clickedDiv.animate({
           left: -distance
        }, 2000),
        prevDiv.animate({
            left: distance
        }, 2000)).done(function () {
            prevDiv.css('left', '0px');
            clickedDiv.css('left', '0px');
            clickedDiv.insertBefore(prevDiv);
            animating = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this help http://jqueryui.com/sortable/?

Comment: No, thanks I don't want to use jQueriUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITTED:**

To swap the clicked div **only with the first element**, you have to change the script. The `prevDiv` variable is selecting the previous sibiling the apply the switch, but you want to change it to:

```
prevDiv = $("#container > :first-child")
```

so it always selects the first child of the container.

Then, add the condition that the clicked element cannot be the first one:

```
if (!clickedDiv.is(":first-child")) {
```

Finally, to swap correctly, place the `prevDiv` at the place where the clicked div was, and set the `clickedDiv` to be the first child with `prependTo('')`:

```
prevDiv.insertBefore(clickedDiv);
clickedDiv.prependTo("#container");
```

And, **now**, you're good to go: http://jsfiddle.net/exc5m046/3/

Comment: Thanks but it should swap always with the first child. fiddle don;t work properly if you click on div_3 it animates well but div_2 goes where div_1 should go. Can u check please

Comment: You want it to swap with whichever is first child, or div number 1?

Comment: Always with the first child.

Comment: Just to mention: `clickedDiv.hasClass("first")` will look more logical and maybe even work faster.

Comment: Yes but It should swap with the first-child always.

Comment: @LcSalazar what is variable `animating` for? It's value is never read.

Comment: I didn't set that. It was there before... Probably will be useful to the OP.

Comment: @LcSalazar okay, I see. Just one more thing: why did you write `var clickedDiv = $(this).closest('div'),` instead of simple `var clickedDiv = $(this),`? EDIT: well, finally I looked at question's code and see that you just save it "as is"

Comment: `.closest` is also not mine... But @rexhin should take that comment in consideration...

Answer (score 1):

Edit, updated

Try

html

```
<!-- removed class `first` from element at index 0 -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="move">div 1</div>
    <div id="two" class="move">div 2</div>
    <div id="three" class="move">div 3</div>
</div>
```

js

```
var animating = false;

$('#container').on('click', '.move', function () {

    var clickedDiv = $(this).closest('div'),

        // adjusted `prevDiv` to `$(".move").eq(0)`
        prevDiv = $(".move").eq(0),
        distance = clickedDiv.offset().left - prevDiv.offset().left;

    if (/*!clickedDiv.is(".first") &&*/ prevDiv.length) {
        animating = true;
        $.when(clickedDiv.animate({
           left: -distance
        }, 2000),
        prevDiv.animate({
            left: distance
        }, 2000)).done(function () {
            prevDiv.css('left', '0px');
            clickedDiv.css('left', '0px');
            // changed `clickedDiv.insertBefore(prevDiv);` to 
            // `clickedDiv.prependTo("#container");`
            clickedDiv.prependTo("#container");
            animating = false;
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/exc5m046/14/

See http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Comment: Thanks but thats not a problem. The problem is during the animation not in DOM update. :)

Comment: @rexhin If possible , can describe required effect ? Thanks

Comment: It works only the first time you click. :/ It must be another problem I think. @guest271314

Comment: When a user clicks a div with class .move It should alawys swap with the first child of the parent, in other words It should go where div with id #one was when the page loads. Exept the user clicks the first div, in this case nothing should happen.  @guest271314

Comment: Is it possible to get the order of divs after the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#container div').on('click', '.move', function () {
  if ( $( this ).index() == 0 ) {
    return
  } else {
    //...code
  }
}
```

This triggers your code only, if the `div` is not the [first element](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in the parent `#container`.

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely appropriate on SO. Try to add some explanation as to *what* your code does and *why* it should be used.